# Why alias inside function does not work?

Tags: shell, shell-script, alias, function, dash

See the code below:

```
a()(alias x=echo\ hi;type x;alias;x);a
```

I have an alias inside a function, I do not want to change the external environment (that is why I am using `()` instead of `{}`), even the code saying the alias was successfully setted, it does not work, check the output out:

```
x is aliased to `echo hi'
...
alias x='echo hi'
x: command not found
```

I heard about doing `shopt -s expand_aliases` would solve, but not only it has not had any effect as well as I could not depend on `bash` because I am working with `dd-wrt`'s `busybox`'s `ash`.

Someone know this issue?

Comment: Why are you using an alias in there, anyway?

Comment: @muru in dd-wrt I need to save bytes, so I use alias a lot, because it is shorter than a function and a variable: beginning with `alias a=alias` I can do `a e=echo` vs `e()(echo "$@")`, and it is better than `e=echo` because it needs to be called as `$e args` vs just `e args`.

Comment: I guess eval defeats the purpose then.

Comment: @muru - not necessarily. If you `eval` the alias assignment you might come off with it - depending on shell/context. Another simple thing could be to define a fn within the function and use it w/ parameters/`eval` to define/call aliases at will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not averse to using `eval`:

```
$ busybox ash -c 'a()(alias x=echo\ hi;type x;alias;eval x);a'
x is an alias for echo hi
x='echo hi'
hi
```

I have no idea why this works.

Comment: This is the answer and the reason is `eval` gives the parser another pass - the function is a literal string of text stored in memory executed at once as a substitution - it doesnt get the same treatment as an input file does in which the parser gets to both evaluate the assignment in one command context and its execution in another - it just runs. Introducing `eval` gives the shell a chance to check the string it has stored in memory a second time over.

Comment: It works, although I will try an alternative way to do the same

Answer (score 5):

I don't use `dash`, but here is what `bash` manual has to say about aliases:

> The rules concerning the definition and use of aliases are somewhat
>   confusing.  **Bash
>          always reads at least one complete line of input before executing any  of  the  commands  on  that  line**.   Aliases are expanded when a command is read, not when it is
>          executed.  Therefore, an alias definition appearing on the same line as another command  does  not take effect until the next line of input is read.  **The commands following the alias definition on that line are not affected by the  new  alias**.   This
>          behavior  is also an issue when functions are executed.  Aliases are expanded when a
>          function definition is read, not when the function is executed, because  a  function
>          definition  is  itself  a  compound command.  As a consequence, aliases defined in a
>          function are not available until after that  function  is  executed.   To  be  safe,
>          always  put  alias  definitions on a separate line, and do not use alias in compound
>          commands.

And another quote, this time from `zsh` manual:

> There  is  a  commonly encountered problem with aliases illustrated by the following code:
>
> ```
>           alias echobar='echo bar'; echobar
> ```
>
> This prints a message that the command `echobar` could not  be  found.   This  happens because aliases  are  expanded when the code is read in; **the entire line is read in one go**, so that when `echobar` is executed it is too late to expand the newly  defined
>          alias.  **This is often a problem in shell scripts, functions, and code executed with
>          `source` or `.`**.  Consequently, use of functions rather than aliases is  recommended
>          in non-interactive code.

I'm pretty sure it is similar in other shells as well.

Comment: No, I don't think that's it. You can test it out by inserting as many new lines as you want, but it still says `ash: x: not found`.

Comment: Ah, damn. You're right. That bit about aliases not being available until after the function is executed. Which means re-executing this function won't be of use, given it is using a sub shell.

Comment: "Aliases are expanded when a command is read, not when it is executed." I think this is happening when the script or input is initially **parsed**. So the alias inside the function is expanded (or not expanded) before any commands are executed (before the alias is actually defined at runtime).