# alias inside a script returns command not found

Tags: bash, shell-script, alias

Using bash in a Debian system.

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

I defined an `alias` inside a function. I use this alias to write to a log file. Since I run this command as non-privileged user, I'm using tee to do this: alias is not found.

I get:

```
./test.sh 
Preparing Environment...
/tmp/support/20200525_074655
./test.sh: line 19: WRITE_LOG: command not found
./test.sh: line 20: ifconfig: command not found
./test.sh: line 20: WRITE_LOG: command not found
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash


function prepare_environment() {
    echo "Preparing Environment..."
    TICKET_ID=$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
    LOG_LOCATION=/tmp/support/"${TICKET_ID}"
    sudo mkdir -p "${LOG_LOCATION}" 
    echo "${LOG_LOCATION}"
    alias WRITE_LOG='sudo tee -a "${LOG_LOCATION}"/report.log  > /dev/null'
}

function write_log() {
    sudo tee -a "${LOG_LOCATION}"/report.log  > /dev/null
}


function collect_information() {
    echo "Current Report time: $(date '+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M.%S')" | WRITE_LOG
    ifconfig | WRITE_LOG
}   

prepare_environment
echo "Current Report time: $(date '+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M.%S')" | write_log
collect_information
```

Alternatives:

- I have various commands, instead of doing `sudo command > file.log` I though this would be a cleaner way to do it.
- I can do `sudo command | write_log`

Similar [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180683/why-alias-inside-function-does-not-work)

Comment: If you have to use `sudo`, then why not just run the script as `root`?

Answer (score 3):

[Bash does not expand aliases in scripts by default, only when it's interactive](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases).

You can enable alias expansion, but there's no point. Just use the function.

---

As for `ifconfig`, you can use it as an unprivileged user to obtain information, but not to modify the system configuration. Many distributions don't put it in the `PATH` of unprivileged users. Add `sbin` directories to the `PATH` in your script:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH
```

Comment: Uprated because you have the core answer, although "there's no point" is a judgement, and hard to justify without looking at the particular case.